# Read a list of zip files and extract the year from the filename in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I'm trying to read a list of zip files in Pandas and combine them into one data frame. How could I extract the year from the file name, such as 2014, into a new column called 'YEAR' into the dataframe? Thank you!

```
files = ['CollegeScorecard_Data/MERGED2013_14_PP.zip',
 'CollegeScorecard_Data/MERGED2014_15_PP.zip',
 'CollegeScorecard_Data/MERGED2017_18_PP.zip',
 'CollegeScorecard_Data/MERGED2009_10_PP.zip',
 'CollegeScorecard_Data/MERGED2016_17_PP.zip',
 'CollegeScorecard_Data/MERGED2011_12_PP.zip',
 'CollegeScorecard_Data/MERGED2015_16_PP.zip',
 'CollegeScorecard_Data/MERGED2010_11_PP.zip',
 'CollegeScorecard_Data/MERGED2012_13_PP.zip']



 frames = []
 for file in files:

    df = pd.read_csv(file,compression='zip', low_memory=False)
    frames.append(df)

pd.concat(frames)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try concat():

```
frames = []
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file,compression='zip')
    # there several ways to get the year; here's one
    df['YEAR'] =  file.split('MERGED')[1].split('_')[0]
    frames.append(df)

pd.concat(frames)
```

Comment: Or Simply : `final_df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file, compression='zip') for file in files], 1)
`

Comment: where in the code is the year data extracted from the file name and included in the data frame?

Comment: missed that part; updated answer to include adding year to df